# How to print argv arguments?

Tags: assembly, arm, arguments, printf, argv

```
.global main

main:
    ldr r0, =message_format
    b   printf

message_format:
    .asciz "argv: %s\n"
```

If I execute it I got this:

```
# ./a.out 7
argv: ^?~^?~
```

How can I "pass" to printf my argv ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`argv` is a pointer to a list of length `argc + 1` of pointers to argument strings, where the last element is a `NULL` pointer.

`ldr r1, [r1,#4]` will load the second element of `argv` (`argv[1]`) to `r1`. This is a pointer to the first argument string after the program name. (generally)

You're passing this string pointer to `printf` as an integer, which is incorrect, and would lead to it printing what seems to be an arbitrary value.

All `argv` elements are strings, so there is no additional transformation necessary. You just need to tell `printf` to expect a string instead of an integer, by changing the `"%i"` to a `"%s"`.

---

Note that this is only valid if you are sure that there is a second element. You should always check that `argv[0]` is non-`NULL` or that `argc` is greater than 0 before accessing `argv[1]`. You should then also check that `argv[1]` is non-`NULL` or that `argc` is greater than 1 before accessing the string pointed to by `argv[1]`.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the code but stil doesn't work. I removed `ldr r1, [r1,#4]` and but %s. Look in the thread to see the output

Comment: No, keep the `ldr`. You need that to get the string. Make sure you've familiarized yourself with the meaning of the instructions in this ISA, the calling convention, and what you're trying to do.